# "failed to fetch builder image ... Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix" error while building docker image with buildpacksio/pack

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bamboo, buildpack

While launching on my laptop (MacOS) OR on my CI/CD tools (Atlassian Bamboo):

```
docker run --volume "/Users/username/Documents/git/myapp:/data" --workdir /data --rm buildpacksio/pack:latest build myapp:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --env "BP_MAVEN_BUILT_ARTIFACT=target/myapp.jar"
```

I'm facing following error:

```
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base': Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I also try following launch in order to solve what I guess is a 'Docker in Docker' issue:

```
docker run --privileged=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/Users/username/Documents/git/myapp:/data" --workdir /data --rm buildpacksio/pack:latest build myapp:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --env "BP_MAVEN_BUILT_ARTIFACT=target/myapp.jar"
```

But now facing a 'permission denied' error:

```
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base': Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/images/create?fromImage=paketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder&tag=base": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

My need seems to be common so any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

Use 'buildpacksio/pack:**0.13.1**' image instead of more recent one.

**Details**

I do not have any 'docker in docker' issue with image tagged 0.13.1 or lowest.

So it is now working fine with following command:

```
docker run --privileged=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/Users/username/Documents/git/myapp:/data" --workdir /data buildpacksio/pack:0.13.1 build myapp:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --env "BP_MAVEN_BUILT_ARTIFACT=target/myapp.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try mounting the docker.sock file with:

```
-v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:Z"
```

I know from experience that without the ":Z" part docker mounts the file as a directory instead.

*Update:* I'm wrong about the `:Z` part. It's the part `...:/var/run/docker.sock` that tells docker to the file as a file and not a directory. You can remove the `:Z` suffix.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, trying but having 'permission denied' error. (I update my question since I was not talking about this 'permission denied error before, sorry)

Comment: What do you get if you run `$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock busybox ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`: `srwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Apr 23 12:24 /var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock busybox ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
f531cdc67389: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ae39a6f5c07297d7ab64dbd4f82c77c874cc6a94cea29fdec309d0992574b4f7
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
srwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Apr 27 09:20 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Then you're not using `root` user.